# Python Pandas exclude text form regex

Tags: python, regex, text

I understand the negative look ahead function in regex, but I am not so sure that it applies directly to this case as I want to ignore all cases with EOL.  Can you please tell me how to create a non match from `EOL I11011` and a match from `942194`, `42143` and `weoijf23412dfd`

I am currently using this regex pattern `[^0-9]*([9|0]?[0-9]{5})[^0-9]*`

Comment: Maybe [`^([09]?\d{5})$`](https://regex101.com/r/eASh4n/1) is enough?

Comment: I should specify that there could be many different strings in front of these digits

Comment: Then [`\b([09]?\d{5})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eASh4n/4). Try this version with word boundaries.

Comment: and what if there is text attached to the digit?  asdfoij38921as;dlkf for example

Comment: Acc. to your examples, this should not be matched. If you have specific requirements, please add. **Why should  a match be found in `weoijf23412dfd` if it should not be found in `EOL I11011`**?

Comment: No, it is not clear. Please answer my comment above.

Comment: EOL should cause the EOL I11011 to completely ignore the string basically

Comment: `EOL` or `EOL`+`whitespaces`+`letters/alphanumeric chars`?

Comment: Ok, let me revamp the answer.

Comment: EOL + whitespaces+letters/alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `[^0-9]*` could not be used to restrict the context around your expected values because `*` quantifier allows the pattern to match an empty string.

To ignore the `EOL` + any word after it, you need to actually *match* it, and then *match and capture* what you need:

```
r'\bEOL\s+\w+|(?<!\d)([09]?\d{5})(?!\d)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eASh4n/6)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `EOL` - an `EOL` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1+ letters/digits/`_`
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\d)` - there should be no digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `([09]?\d{5})` - a capturing group (there must be one so that it could be extracted) matching

  - `[09]?` - an optional `0` or `9` (note you do not need a `|` inside to define the OR relationship, it is default, and `[0|9]` matches `0`, `9` or `|` literal pipe char)
  - `\d{5}` - 5 digits
- `(?!\d)` - there cannot be a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

[**Python demo**](https://ideone.com/xXE6js):

```
import re
rx = r"\bEOL\s+\w+|(?<!\d)([09]?\d{5})(?!\d)"
ss = ["EOL I11011", "942194", "42143", "weoijf23412dfd"]
for s in ss:
    m = re.search(rx, s)
    if m and m.group(1):
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
942194
42143
23412
```

Comment: how does the ´|´ operator distinguish the match here - this is basically how you are negating the EOL U string correct?

Comment: The alternation here makes the regex engine try `\bEOL\s+\w+` pattern first, at each location. Once it is matched, the regex index is moved to the end of the match, and the next match is searched for from that match end position. If the first alternative does not match, only in that case the second one is tried.